# UnknownHost exception for Android application

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, android-emulator

I am able to open an URL from Android web browser, desktop browsers, blackberry application.

But in my android application I am getting this error sporadically. (There is no specific pattern to explain why I am getting this error) Can somebody let me know what could be reason for this?

Thanks & Best Regards
Sudhakar Chavali

Comment: have you looked into DNS setting for your andriod ?

Answer (score 0):

How can you open your web page? Code behind or from textview with autolink attribute?
What is your error message?